# Not enough storage error using net use command

Tags: windows-7, nas, shared-folders, net-use

I'm getting the error "Not enough storage is available to process this command." In Windows 7 attempting to connect to a shared folder on a NAS device.

Google searches suggested increasing the IRPStackSize. So I kept increasing it until I hit the maximum value of 50, but I am still getting the error message.

Any ideas what else it could be? I verified that I'm not low on physical memory or hard disk storage space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
1- Type `Windows +R` to bring Run...
2- Type `Regedit.exe`.
3- Navigate to:`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\MemoryManagement\LargeSystemCache`
 Set it to `1`
4- Navigate to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size` Set it to `3`
5- Save Changes and Restart yourPC.